# How to share a link via social media in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, share, social-media

I need to create app where user is able to share link through apps like Instagram or TikTok. Available Flutter packages make it possible to share through apps that are shown in share sheet, but e.g. Instagram doesn't show up there on iOS.

I have tried multiple Flutter packages like [share_plus](https://pub.dev/packages/share_plus), flutter_share_me package, appinio_social_share, share_it, social_share package etc.

Sharing functionality is very popular, how do Flutter developers deal with this issue?